# Adding radio button of customize listview in radio group

Tags: android

I am currently working on customize listview in which i had extends array adapter and using getview method of it displayed each row with radio button on extreme right and item name on left side of each row now i want to put all radio button in radio group so that only one of it get selected at a time,but i am gettin exception as  java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.

here is basic code snippet which create this error.

class MyCustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter
and in getView()

```
if (row==null)  
{                                       
   row=inflater.inflate(R.layout.row, parent, false);

   RadioButton toggle1=(RadioButton)row.findViewById(com.example.ToggleButtonExample.R.id.toggle_id);
   //this is radio button which i had created in row.xml

   radio1.addView(toggle1); //create error here

 }
```

Answer (score 0):

hi first you need to add radiobutton to radio group then to listview go through the link below it will help you.[radiogroup issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588827/listview-with-radio-group-error)