# Android: ArrayAdapter with RadioButton

Tags: android, android-layout

I found this code that works very good and I have to create something of very similar but with RadioButton. What would I have to change?

```
    public class InteractiveArrayAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Model> {

    private final List<Model> list;
    private final Activity context;

    public InteractiveArrayAdapter(Activity context, List<Model> list) {
        super(context, R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, list);
        this.context = context;
        this.list = list;
    }

    static class ViewHolder {
        protected TextView text;
        protected CheckBox checkbox;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflator = context.getLayoutInflater();
            view = inflator.inflate(R.layout.rowbuttonlayout, null);
            final ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
            viewHolder.text = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.label);
            viewHolder.checkbox = (CheckBox) view.findViewById(R.id.check);
            viewHolder.checkbox
                    .setOnCheckedChangeListener(new CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener() {

                        @Override
                        public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView,
                                boolean isChecked) {
                            Model element = (Model) viewHolder.checkbox
                                    .getTag();
                            element.setSelected(buttonView.isChecked());

                        }
                    });
            view.setTag(viewHolder);
            viewHolder.checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        } else {
            view = convertView;
            ((ViewHolder) view.getTag()).checkbox.setTag(list.get(position));
        }
        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        holder.text.setText(list.get(position).getName());
        holder.checkbox.setChecked(list.get(position).isSelected());
        return view;
    }
}



    public class Model {

    private String name;
    private boolean selected;

    public Model(String name) {
        this.name = name;
        selected = false;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public boolean isSelected() {
        return selected;
    }

    public void setSelected(boolean selected) {
        this.selected = selected;
    }

}
```

"rowbuttonlayout.xml".

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/label"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@+id/label"
        android:textSize="30px" >
    </TextView>

    <CheckBox
        android:id="@+id/check"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4px"
        android:layout_marginRight="10px" >
    </CheckBox>

</RelativeLayout>
```

I found all this code on this [website](http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidListView/article.html).

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find all required info in this already answered question :

[listview with radio group error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8588827/listview-with-radio-group-error)

The accepted answer of @Dante includes all the required code for you to rewrite the custom array adapter to use radiobuttons.

EDIT

According to your comment I am not sure you really know how to write a custom list with Custom Adapter, view Holder and Object.

Romain Guy explains listview in details here

http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html

and the related pdf

http://dl.google.com/googleio/2010/android-world-of-listview-android.pdf

Once you handel customadapter viewholder etc you simply have to have your list implements checkable. as for example here

[How to use RadioGroup in ListView custom adapter?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329856/how-to-use-radiogroup-in-listview-custom-adapter)

If you don't know how to set a custom list view here is an example, but it's not directly related to your question :

```
// The Adapter
class myObjectAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<myObject> {
    myObjectAdapter() {
        super(MyActivity.this, R.layout.my_row_layout,
                listItems);
    }

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        myObjectHolder holder = null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.my_row_layout,
                    parent, false);
            holder = new myObjectHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (myObjectHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.populateFrom(listItems.get(position));
        return (convertView);
    }
}

// The Holder
static class myObjectHolder {
    private TextView myText = null;        

    myObjectHolder(View row) {
        myText = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.MyTextView);            
    }

    void populateFrom(myObject r) {
        myText.setText(r.getText());            
    }
}

// The Object
class myObject {        
    public final String myText;        

    public myObject(String myText) {            
        this.myText = myText;            
    }

    public String getText() {
        return myText;
    }                
}
```

assuming you have an xml file called my_row_layout which contains a textview called MyTextView. In your case you will replace the textview with a radiobutton and according to the link given above implemnt checkable and it'll work.

Hope it helps

Comment: There is a problem in the Dante's solution. He creates exactly 5 RadioButton! I have to create the same RadioButton dynamycally because I don't know the number. How can I do?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7329856/how-to-use-radiogroup-in-listview-custom-adapter <- This post doesn't help me. 

Your example is very useful and this http://www.google.com/events/io/2010/sessions/world-of-listview-android.html is helpful to understand the question. 

Now I created the same thing with the radiobutton but I don't know why it is possible check to many button and not only one... I guess that the problem is that I don't set the radiogroup, but I don't know where I can set it!

I'm sorry for the newbie question but I'm using android only from 2 week...

Comment: Ok great, you now have a list with radiobutton, and you need to have only 1 checked at a time. Even though you say "stackoverflow.com/questions/7329856/… <- This post doesn't help me" I think it should help, you are now in the same state. You have to do 2 things. use CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE and implement checkable in your view row.